# test a facebook post with selenium and phpunit

Tags: facebook-graph-api, selenium, phpunit

I have a script that posts to a users Facebook when a user action is completed. Therefore i would like to automate the process of testing/seeing has this post appeared on the wall of the user (and maybe delete it when its been seen through a teardown function)

Is automation of a test possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if user granted `publish_stream` permission to your application, once you have `publish_stream` permission you can post to user's feed using [application `access_token`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/).

feed stories published by your application can be also deleted via Graph API (actually application can only delete stories it created)...